# Passing a url as argument

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

Whenever I try to run the script as below, I get the following results. What is wrong with the code?

1.`python test.py`

doesn't print the usage.

2.`python test.py http://link.com/index.php?title=tesst&action=raw`

prints:
 `"'action' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."`

My script:

```
# Version YYYYMMDD
version = "20121112"

# File type to be output to logs
# Should be changed to exe before building the exe.
fileType = "py"

# Import sys to read command line arguments
import sys, getopt
#import pdb
#pdb.set_trace()

import argparse

def update (url):
    req = urllib2.Request(url=url)
    try:
        f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        txt = f.read()
        f.close()
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        txt = ''
        print 'An error occured connecting to the wiki. No wiki page will be generated.'
        return '<font color=\"red\">QWiki</font>'
    # Find the start tag of the textarea with Regular Expressions
    p = re.compile('<textarea[^>]*>')
    m = p.search(txt)
    (tagStart, tagEnd) = m.span()
    # Find the end of the textarea
    endTag = txt.index("</textarea>")

def main ():
    #For logging
    print "test"
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This is the update.py script created by test')
    parser.add_argument('-u','--ur',action='store',dest='url',default=None,help='<Required> url link',required=True)
    results = parser.parse_args()# collect cmd line args
    url = results.url
    print url
    update(url)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrap the URL in quotes:

```
python test.py "http://link.com/index.php?title=tesst&action=raw"
```

The `&` is confusing Command Prompt.

Comment: @blendar - if i dont pass any argument..why isnt it printing the usage?

Comment: also am printing url as "print url",it just doesnt print anything